# Project errors when creating an Android app in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have been trying to figure his out for a while. I have created a project in Eclipse Luna for Android Development. I keep getting the following error: The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library '/Users/joshuadavid/Documents/workspace/Java IEDP/appcompat_v7/bin/appcompat_v7.jar'   TestApp     Build path  Build Path Problem.

I have tried to clean the project. I have tried to "Fix Project Properties" in Android Tools. I can't seem to figure it out for the life of me. When I try to got the "Quick Fix" route here is what I see: [image: screenshot] Any ideas?

Comment: Removing all the jar files from libs folder might work.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. The problem seemed to be in the eclipse.ini where i added `-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home` After I removed that line and saved my .ini file, everything worked nicely. I assume that eclipse fixed the issue with having to add that line in the JDK 1.8 version. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

It means your project can't load the `appcompat_v7.jar` at all. It is gone or something. You need to import the `appcompat` v7 jar again if you indeed need it.

Try this:

right-click your project-->`Properties`-->`Java Build Path`-->`Libraries`-->`Android Dependencies`-->`Remove`-->`OK`.

Then you need reimport then `appcompat` project.

Try this:

right-click your project-->`Properties`-->`Android`-->`Add`-->select the `android-support-v7-appcompat`-->`OK`-->`OK`.
If you don't have the support v7 project, import it from your `.../sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat` as orders above.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried this and the android-support-v7-appcompat doesn't come up as an option. It seemed to remove the Android Dependencies error, but when I restart Eclipse, the error comes back. I also have the following errors after. [link](http://i.imgur.com/oOzv278.png) as well as [link](http://i.imgur.com/dPn3nQK.png) any other ideas? How can I make it so that I don't have to use the appcompat v7 jar?

Comment: If you don't want to use `appcompat-v7` jar, you need not extend your activities from `ActionbarActivity`. At the meantime, you need to do like this: right-click your project-->`Properties`-->`Android`-->select the `android-support-v7-appcompat`-->`Remove`-->OK

Comment: When I do as you mentioned 'remove android-support-v7-appcompat' I now have these 11 [errors](http://i.imgur.com/CLIWDEx.png)

Comment: @jshuadvd Of course. So I recommend you " Don't extend your activities from `ActionbarActivity`." So extend all your Activities from `Activity`

Comment: I am confused now. This is how the project is set up from default. Should I create another public class called Activity?

Comment: No, don't. you need to do like this:<br/>`public class YourActivity extends Activity`<br/> And the `Activity` is from `android.jar`, is `ActionbarActivity`'s parent class, which is from `android-support-v7-appcompat`.

Comment: Still not resolving the issues. It just creates more... :(